# How to inspect two golang functions' invoke relations?

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on a code static analysis, and I have a challenge now. For example I have two go source file.

a.go

```
package test1
func Func1() {
    test2.Func2()
    fmt.println("func1")
}
```

b.go

```
package test2
func Func2() {
    fmt.println("func2")
}
```

How to check if func1 ast node has invoke relation with func2 ast node in Golang?

Comment: You may want to look at [this](https://github.com/dominikh/go-tools/tree/master/staticcheck)

Comment: And seems like [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41630530/6426898) will help you

Comment: Maybe I did not describe my question clearly, I just want to check the invoke relationship statically. I noticed that the discussion above focus mainly on runtime reflection.

Comment: It's not really relevant to the question but your sample code is invalid. `test1` cannot call `test2.func2` because it is not exported.