# How to dynamically call all methods of a struct in Golang?

Tags: go, reflection

I'm building a library where once methods are added to a struct we want them to be automatically called w/o using some sort of method list.

I want to build on the work here by calling all of the methods dumped that is linked here [How to dump methods of structs in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397653/how-to-dump-methods-of-structs-in-golang).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    Prop string
}

func (f Foo) Bar(i int) {
    fmt.Println("Called from Foo.Bar()")
}

func (f Foo) Baz(i int) {
    fmt.Println("Called from Foo.Baz()")
}

func (f Foo) Floop(i int) {
    fmt.Println("Called from Foo.Floop()")
}

func main() {
    fooType := reflect.TypeOf(&Foo{})

    fmt.Println("--- Calling methods ---")
    for i := 0; i < fooType.NumMethod(); i++ {
        method := fooType.Method(i)

        method.Func.Call(nil)
    }
}
```

Also seen here: https://play.golang.org/p/gNUsANjuPV0

This will always panic w/ a message for too few arguments to .Call(). I don't see where this differs structurally from the code here: https://play.golang.org/p/HB8yB91LRme.

Comment: Hint 1: In the linked example the method takes NO arguments and yet is supplied one in ‘Call’. Hint 2: see the documentation for ‘Call’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the method from the *type*, you must pass a `reflect.Value` instance that provides the `Foo` object that is the receiver *plus* a `reflect.Value` instance that provides the `int` argument that each function receives:

```
fooType := reflect.TypeOf(&Foo{})
fooVal := reflect.ValueOf(&Foo{})
fmt.Println("--- Calling methods ---")
for i := 0; i < fooType.NumMethod(); i++ {
    method := fooType.Method(i)
    arg := i + 10
    method.Func.Call([]reflect.Value{fooVal, reflect.ValueOf(arg)})
}
```

for instance.  Note that if you call the method from the *value*, the receiver is provided via that value, so we get to drop the first argument:

```
    arg = i + 20
    reflect.Indirect(fooVal).Method(i).Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(arg)})
```

[complete example on Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_W6KJTm2Bti)—but note that we only need to obtain the `foo` object once, above the loop over its methods: https://play.golang.org/p/HHk_mO2KXc6 so that the last line in the loop is just:

```
    fooObj.Method(i).Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(arg)})
```